# How to judge a empty object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I render the html  in php ,and use jQuery   .they have such  html code :

```
<div>
    <tr class="selectClass"></tr>
    <tr class="selectClass"></tr>
</div>
```

In some condition , it will remove this  `<tr class="selectClass"></tr>`,
and become :

```
<div>

</div>
```

I have to judge this two situations ,I try  different  way , but the result is strange .

```
  var selectTr  = $('.selectClass') ;

   if( selectTr ){
      console.log("i am undefined") ; 
   }
```

it do not print anything .

```
  var selectTr  = $('.selectClass') ;

   if( typeof (selectTr) == "undefined"  ){
      console.log("i am undefined") ; 
   }
```

it do not print "i am undefined " . 
so i  try  it 
`console.log(typeof (selectTr))`
 , it is **object**  .

## My problem is that :

how to judge a empty object and why it is object instead of null  or undefined?

Comment: The provided HTML is invalid, `div` is not a permitted parent for [`tr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr).

Comment: Firstly, you cannot have `tr` elements as children of a `div`. Secondly, use the `length` property to determine how many elements were found by the selector.

Comment: An empty DOM object is not undefined. It is defined. It just doesn't have any children. I suggest studying real javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check the length of the selected element like

```
if($('.selectClass').length === 0){
   //there is no element with the class selectClass
}
```

This is the best way to achieve what you want.